# Classify huge CSV file by tag name

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a large size CSV file that is almost 60MB. This CSV file contains Object_Name, timestamp, and value.

In the CSV file, there are 10 objects that are listed in csv file based on time sequence, but those are overlap. such as :

```
A1,2013-08-24 15:36:47,24.83
A2,2013-08-24 15:36:47,26.56
A3,2013-08-24 15:36:47,25.83
A6,2013-08-24 15:36:47,-40
A8,2013-08-24 15:36:47,-40
A9,2013-08-24 15:36:47,-40
B2,2013-08-24 15:36:47,6
C1,2013-08-24 15:37:18,6
```

I want to classfy those records by object_name. If the size of file is small, I can do it. In this situation, I spend 10 mins to read the csv file. I could not image to classify the data, probably crash my laptop. The expected results are 10 list, each of them contain only one object with timestamp and value, such as,

```
Object_Name,timestamp,val
A1,2013-08-24 15:00:00,26.7
   .....
   .....
```

Could someone help me? Basically, I just want to know a effective way which sorts these data by object name and separates from it.

BTW, I use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read) to read csv file.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "classify"?

Comment: Hi Jim, I want to know how to sort by object name, and separate it from huge CSV file.

Comment: I use CSVReader, so all data from csv are read into List<String[]> listString = reader.readAll(). The next thing is separate each object by sorting object_name. My solution is using 10 List<String[]> store 10 object which contains name, timestamp, val.

Comment: You could dump the data into a database, and then query it.  With such a large dataset this could be the most efficient way.

Comment: Have you tried using the `sort` command on Linux?  There may be a sort in Linux-like environments for Windows, like Cygwin.  `sort --field-separator="," --key=1 <infile >outfile `  Once you have a sorted file, it is no longer necessary to slurp the entire file into memory, you could use a streaming model to split the file into files based on the first key.

Comment: Done it.
First, Read the csv file into memory, then do For loop separate different object, after that insert these data into different table in database.